# Acrescentar o items a um controlo dropdown ligado a uma base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown

Tenho um controlo `dropdown` ligado a uma BD e queria acrescentar um item para forçar o utilizador a escolher uma opção.

Como posso acrescentar um outro item (escolher/seleccionar/--------) ao controlo de forma a forçar o utilizador a fazer a escolha?

Já tentei acrescentar através do `Edit Items...` mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua `dropdownlist`, mude a propriedade `AppendDataBoundItems` para `True`. Os items que adicionar agora através do `Edit Items...` vão aparecer juntamente com os itens da BD.